# Displacement modifier mars picture it's applied to

Tags: displacement, 2d

I am using displace modifier to imitate cloth movement from wind on 2d plane. It deforms image the way I want but it all adds visual color noise on picture that I don't want. Any suggestions on how to get rid of this? To add more clarity, now it looks like there are clouds moving before the texture.
[image: Added gif]
[image: what I use]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please add blend file

Comment: I think that you're just seeing the specular changing as the vertices displace.  If you don't want specular, edit the material to remove it.  (Exact method depends on your material.)  You'll still have some variation from any diffuse component, but it won't be as noticeable; if you don't want that, then use an emission shader instead.  If you *really* want specular+diffuse, but without changing, you could transfer normals from a non-rendering, non-displaced copy of the mesh using a data transfer modifier.

Comment: @Nathan got it fixed. Thank you